# Cocoa Webview - Camouflage webview as native control

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

OK, I'm doing some experiments with WebView-based native OSX apps, and I'm wondering:

- Which are the necessary steps in order to fully camouflage it? (So, that the user - ok, a non-technical user, actually) cannot possibly understand it's a webview.
- How can we eliminate the right-click menu (including the "Reload" item)?

---

Last but not least:

If the actual webpage content is loaded on startup (in `awakeFromNib`), even for a simple webpage, it takes 1-or-2 seconds *before* the actual content shows up. During this time, a white/empty background shows where the webview/page should be. What could I do about that? Perhaps a "loading" indicator?

---

Any help will be appreciated! :-)

Comment: For the second part, could you just not hide the webview behind another view until it has finished loading at which point you could remove the view and like you say you could have a loading screen or something the user can interact with, users like things to interact with. I've developed an app for my company that does something similar on iOS although it is just a loading screen that saying retrieving data when in fact its retrieving nothing and actually loading the webapp behind the view but when the webapp has loaded it looks and feels like the rest of the native app.

Comment: @Popeye Well, that's quite an interesting idea. I'll give it a try! Thanx! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the right click menu implement the `webView(_:contextMenuItemsForElement:defaultMenuItems:)` method of [WebUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/index.html) protocol.